# Angular2 - How to close WebSocketSubject underlying socket

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

Is there a way to obtain the socket being subscribed by WebSocketSubject?

When a certain condition happens I need to close the underlying socket.

I tried to close it by complete() but it didn't close the socket. The unsubscribed doesn't work either.

Could anybody help me? Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

He said that the unsubscribe did not work. Indeed I had the same problem. I was doing the unsubscribe and it wasn't closed.

I end up using directly the websocket instead of WebSocketSubject, so I could call the method close (which worked).

```
         this._ws = new WebSocket(this.url);
         this.messages = Observable.create((observer) => {
             this._ws.addEventListener('message', (message) => (
                // Et on ajoute chaque message dans l'Observable
                observer.next(message)
              ), false);

              // On s'enregistre au erreurs qui surviendraient
              // dans la websocket
              this._ws.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
                // Si un erreur est survenue, on prévient
                // l'Observable
                console.log('error ws');

                observer.error(error)

              }, false);

              // On s'enregistre à la fermeture du websocket
              this._ws.addEventListener('close', () => {
                // On met fin à l'Observable
                observer.complete()

                console.log('complete');
              }, false)
         })
    ... 

    public close() {
        console.log('on closing WS');
        this._ws.close()
    }
```

I follow this tuto [Introduction à RxJS](https://www.julienpradet.fr/tutoriels/introduction-a-rxjs/) and [this one](https://medium.com/@lwojciechowski/websockets-with-angular2-and-rxjs-8b6c5be02fac)

If you manage to do a reconnect after the server closes the WS, please post it also.

Thanks

Comment: I found a way to make the reconnection and to know if the server is dead. I let you the answer in another question I asked myself a few days ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49316097/1966439

Answer (score 1):

For having correct socket disconnect you should unsubscribe websocketsubject itself, not it's subscription: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L295

Answer (score 0):

More accurate way is to call `complete()` on `WebSocketSubject`. But there is one more solution. You can obtain socket using code like this. It`s bad, but works too.

```
var wrapper: any = subject;
wrapper._socket.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use unsubscribe method.

```
closeConnection(): void {
    this.socket.unsubscribe();
}
```

Extract for unsubscribe method implemntation :

```
 unsubscribe() {
    const { _socket } = this;
    if (_socket && (_socket.readyState === 1 || _socket.readyState === 0)) {
      _socket.close();
    }
    this._resetState();
    super.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call `unsubscribe()` directly on the `WebSocketSubject` instance that unsubscribes all observers:

```
const subject = Observable.webSocket(...);

...

subject.unsubscribe();
```

See source code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts#L269